# is there an alternative to '#' + div_id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coding-style

Is there a better way to write the following function?

Having the `'#' + div_id` just looks wrong to me.

```
function hide_div(div_id) {
    $('#' + div_id).hide();
}
```

Comment: show us how you are calling `hide_div()`, at present, this is the only way :s

Comment: @SiGanteng the function is just for theoretical purposes, so you understand what I want to know

Comment: You can only transfer the # to the calling place i.e.
 the call `hide_div("#"+div_id);`

Comment: it'd be `hide_div('footer');`

Comment: This function is pretty pointless, why not just call `$("#footer").hide()`?

Comment: @Esailija, that's not what I am trying to do, I came across this a few times, the code above is just an example

Comment: @Esailija This might just be one part of a larger function, but the rest of the function body isn't relevant to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: no. Slightly longer and more hackish answer: create a function with a one-letter long name that takes the element's ID and returns a getElementById on it, then wrap that in your jQuery `$()`, like so:

```
function i(id) {
    if (document.getElementById(id)) return document.getElementById(id);
    else return "";
}
```

Then:

```
$(i(id)).doWhatever();
```

But honestly, think about it:

```
$("#" + id)
  12345678

$(i(id))
  12345
```

That's three characters. Is it worth it? Do those three characters really matter that much to you? You're already saving a lot by not using document.getElementById(id) (27 characters).

Comment: If it's for this, you could've written `function i(id) { return '#'.concat( id ); }`, but I guess your method is more efficient :-)

Comment: Yes, it looks good, I wouldn't bother writing a function to handle it.

Comment: The function could be reduced to `return document.getElementById(id)`.

Comment: I didn't want to return null or some sort of error if the element didn't exist. Besides, the point is brevity in usage, not brevity in the function itself, perse.

Comment: uh, you'd rather send an empty string if the element doesn't exist? There is something wrong there.

Comment: I don't see a try/catch there, so if an error is thrown, it will be thrown regardless. As for returning empty string instead of null, I hope you are trolling.

Answer (score 5):

If you are somehow opposed to the string concatenation, then you could do this instead:

```
$(document.getElementById(div_id)).hide();
```

You could also pass in the fully qualified selector, like this:

```
hide_div("#divId");
```

If you wanted to do it in vanilla Javascript, you could do this:

```
document.getElementById(div_id).style.display = "none";
```

Comment: Note that `.show()/.hide()` are aware of the initial `display` in element. So when you `.show()` on a `.hide()`d table, it will become `"display:table;"` again. So the vanilla javascript is only equivalent in some amount of situations.

Comment: I appreciate that there are a lot of ways of doing this. Although in prototype you can use `$('footer')`, My question was wether something like this existed in jQuery. I know other people wonder about this too. I think it would be a nice jQuery feature

Comment: @Filype: `"footer"` will give you all `footer`-elements whereas `"#footer"` the element with the id `footer`. Prototype works the same way.

Comment: footer might be a bad example, I mean prototype works with `$('myDiv')`

Answer (score 2):

Several alternative ways:

```
$(['#', div_id].join('')).hide();

$('#'.concat(div_id)).hide();
```

Also, @Thomas inspired me for this alternative solution:

When you call your function, use:

```
$.proxy( hide_div, $('#' + div_id) );

// Then, you can do this:
function hide_div() {
    this.hide();
}
```

It may allow you for better reuse. Or not.

Comment: ...how is that an improvement?

Comment: @PeterOlson not an improvement, just another way :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
function hide_div(div_id) {
    $(div_id).hide();
}
```

...where...

```
div_id = '#someId';
hide_div(div_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the use case you could pass the object instead of the id:

```
$('#someobject').click(function(){
    hideDiv(this);
});
```

Answer (score -5):

No, you can't shorten it more than that. An alternative to # + div_id would be :

```
$('[id="'+div_id+'"]')
```

This query is working with [] attribute selector. **Not shorter, not cleaner, really slower but an alternative anyway**

Comment: I know but he asked for an alternative!